# javascript hash table pattern?

Tags: javascript, object, input, hashtable

I'm trying to iterate inside an object and find out if a certain value is already exciting inside that object.
Here is what if done:

```
var contain = {
};
function checkObj(letter){

If(contain.hasOwnProperty(letter)){

return true;

}
else{
return false;
}
}
```

spouse i have a text input with a button to submit.
and for example:

```
$("submit").on("click",function(){
var value = $("input[type=text]").val();
if(function checkObj(value) === false){
contain[value] = value;
}
});
```

then i type in the text input = "b";
which will create a property just like that:
var contain = {
 b: "b"
}
and then next time ill press submit on the input with the value of "b"
it will return false.

is there any better way?
maybe using OOP

Answer (score -1):

`hasOwnProperty` is correct but use `Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty`. Because if the property isn't `"b"` but `"hasOwnProperty"` you will probably get an error saying `hasOwnProperty` isn't a function.

This is a neat little gotcha.

Comment: Care to explain the downvote? A downvote with no competing answers doesn't help OP.